# Grunt run task depending of file modified, it's possible?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, task, watch

can you help-me with this problem?

I need run a specific task depending of file modified, for example:

**Modifie:** _header.scss
**Run:** sass:header task

**Modifie:** _footer.scss
**Run:** sass:footer task

**Modifie:** _banners.scss
**Run:** sass:banners task

I've been trying to get the name of the file at save time to use it as a parameter, but I can not figure out ways to do this.

My project allows more people to work simultaneously but the work of defining which component of the project will be exported to CSS is manual, so I am trying to make this process of compiling the final CSS of each module as automatic.

My problem is how I can identify the name of the modified file, not the type of file.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, grunt will help out with your issues. You can specify different files and tasks inside the grunt watch (gruntfile.js). Here is a quick guide on how to install it: https://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I know how compile files and make tasks with grunt, but my problem is how I identify name of modified file to chnage my tasks based on name of file.

Comment: Define a [watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) task with a target for each file (i.e. `_header.scss`, `_footer.scss`, etc). Each target of the `watch` task can then invoke the appropriate task. For instance; for `_header.scss` and `_footer.scss` your `watch` task will be something like this: `watch: { header: { files: 'path/to/_header.scss', tasks: ['sass:header'] }, footer: { files: 'path/to/_footer.scss', tasks: ['sass:footer'] }, },` Then via your CLI run `grunt watch` and each time `_header.scss` and/or  `_footer.scss` is modified the correct `sass:...` task is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this. When sass files are changed, grunt generates css files and copies (to dist directory) changed files only. Also as far as you can see connect and watch task implement live reload.

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: ...
    livereload: 35729,
    hostname: '127.0.0.1'
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      base: [
        'some dist'
      ]
    }
  }
},
// check that files are changed
watch: {
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
      'your dist/*.css'
    ]
  },
  // when sass file is changed, tasks will run
  // newer:copy means that we have to do task copy with changed files only
  sass: {
    files: ['your dir/*.sass'],
    tasks: ['sass', ...some other tasks like cssmin..., 'newer:copy']
  }
},
sass: {
  dist: {
    files: [
       ...sass to css
    ]
  }
},
copy: {
  css: {
    ....
  }
}
```

Also you can be interested in task like `grunt-changed`. The task configures another task to run with `src` files that have been changed. For more information please check the page [grunt-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-changed)